# The three rules

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

The black rule says: The solution is easy, but not "easy".
The red rule says: The solution is simple, but not "simple".
The golden rule says: The solution is straightforward, but not "straightforward".

What is the solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> All three of those words, Easy, Simple and Straightfoward, translate to "einfach" in German (The German flag being described by the colored rules), which I presume is the answer. Also, not sure if intentional, but a rule can be a type of line (see http://printwiki.org/Rule_Line or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_paper), potentially meaning the "rules" are lines on the flag.

Comment: Very good. That is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

> The German flag is composed of the colors black, red and gold.

If that is the solution, it's indeed straightforward, easy and simple, but I think there should be more to it.

Comment: This is a nice hint.

Answer (score 2):

The answer's already posted, but given the form of the question, I have to wonder if an alternate form of the solution is

> "the solution".

Comment: I  don't see why. Can you please elaborate?